# Best practices to create an AWS architecture for ASP.NET projects

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

I am a beginner in this field and I would like to understand which is the best practice to create a server which offers:

- REST API endpoints (callable via mobile applications) (ASP.NET Core Web API project?);
- RESTful web server (for the website) (ASP.NET Core Web App project?).

I would like to know where to start in terms of:

- The listed VisualStudio ASP.NET project(s) are good for API and dynamic web pages generation (.cshtml)?
- Do I have to maintain in one big VS project or to split it into two. If two or more VS projects (I suppose one for the mobile REST APIs and one for the web pages) are used, how to share the model classes?
- [Extra question] How to CD/CI with the ASP.NET project (deployment, testing, etc...) with GitLab?
- Which services does AWS offer for such project (SQL db and S3 for storage, EC2 for the server?).
- Which is the ideal AWS architecture for a project like this? How to expose the server into the external world and use Cognito tokens?

I am **asking for generic guidance** and articles which I can study, I understand that you cannot provide the straight forward solution here, but I am a little lost.

What I have done until today has been to generate a lot of lambdas (deployed by CloudFormation) which are called by JavaScript on a S3-hosted portal (a complete mess I know...) I would like to understand how to improve the project.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, there's a lot a lot of questions here. You can go with 1 API for both however as your mobile apps should be using the same APIs as your website? If not, 2 web APIs. CI/CD? Gitlab runners with a defacto .NET build pipeline template could be great. SQL DB on AWS is RDS/Aurora, EC2 for self managed server however you have a lot of options. Possibly serverless APIs using Lambdas? Too much here to unpick, I would suggest looking at https://aws.amazon.com/developer/language/net/.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The API could be shared among the app and the website, so you suggest a single project API (ASP.NET Core Web API) right? What about the Web App project with the cshtml? Do you suggest to share a common repo where there are model classes?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of questions here. I will focus on REST API endpoints. You can create a solution using the AWS.NET SDK that can use the Service Client of the Service you want to interact with and return data.

For example, assume you want to build a Rest Solution that queries data from an Amazon Aurora Serverless database and return the data as JSON. (This Rest Service can be used by other apps like a React app, Angular, etc).

To do this, you can use the the **ASP.NET Core Web API** that also uses an [AmazonRDSDataServiceClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=TRDSDataServiceClient.html&tocid=Amazon_RDSDataService_AmazonRDSDataServiceClient) object to perform CRUD operations on the Aurora Serverless database. Then, the web API returns JSON data.

[image]

For example:

```
app.MapGet("/active", async () =>
{
    var database = new RDSService();
    var data = await database.GetItemsData(0); 
    return data;
});
```

Once you create this .NET Backend solution, you have options too where you want to deploy it. You can deploy it within a container using the AWS Fargate Service. Or you can deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk. Of course there are other ways to deploy this .NET solution to the cloud as well.